# Slicing Splicing an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would be the best way to randomly, click-by-click, pick all values of the alphabet (a-z) from a javascript array? So every click would select a random character from the remaining choices and not the beginning array of a-z?

Any point in the right direction would be excellent.

Thanks.

Comment: never extend the prototype of something like the native Array object inside a function called by an event handler like that.

Comment: @newneub Don't change the question fundamentally like you did. It makes the answers seem irrelevant. Not to mention that your new question is not the preferred style of question on StackOverflow. Instead, you should show what you have tried, what didn't work, etc. Much like your initial version.

Comment: @GregL Good call on all accounts. Sorry about that. Frustration + Trying to explain it better = Err.  You JavaScript geniuses and your knowledge, hats off.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `my_array` outside of the function so that you are not redeclaring it each time the function is called, but reusing the same instance. That instance will be modified by `.splice()` each time.

Comment: I am trying to call a modified my_array each time. Are you saying that will work better with my_array out of or inside the function? Thanks..

Comment: It can only work outside the function, otherwise, every time the function is run, it will "reset" the state of `my_array` to have all the options again. What you want is to have a single `my_array` that is initialised once and then modified each time the function is called.